# Raspberry Pi has weird network connectivity

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, raspberry-pi

Got a Raspberry Pi recently and it was fantastically easy to use while it was connected to my network via Ethernet. Now that my WiFi dongle (NETGEAR N150) has arrived it's a bit more fussy.

I'm running it headless and so if it's not connected to the network I can't investigate why it's not.

My /etc/network/interfaces looks like this:

```
auto lo

iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet static
        address 192.168.10.76
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 192.168.10.1

auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
        address 192.168.10.75
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 192.168.10.1
wpa-ssid "MyWiFi"
wpa-psk "MyPassword"
```

(I am terribly sorry that my devices all sit in 192.168.10.0/24, my dad's workplace stupidly decided to run their VPN on 192.168.0.0/24 which caused conflicts and it didn't matter who's fault it was, I was the one that had to make things work)

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:43:04:b5
          inet addr:192.168.10.76  Bcast:192.168.10.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:3538 errors:0 dropped:81 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:15 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:196584 (191.9 KiB)  TX bytes:750 (750.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:28 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:28 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:2352 (2.2 KiB)  TX bytes:2352 (2.2 KiB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr c4:3d:c7:78:06:06
          inet addr:192.168.10.75  Bcast:192.168.10.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:3400 errors:0 dropped:565 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:358 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:424036 (414.0 KiB)  TX bytes:46259 (45.1 KiB)
```

As you can see, onboard Ethernet has a MAC address starting with b8 and the WiFi dongle has C4. (Coincidence, or a premonition?)

Weirdly though, when my Pi is plugged into the network both IP addresses are taken by the same interface. Running nmap on my Windows computer returns one of the following:

```
Nmap scan report for 192.168.10.75
Host is up (0.041s latency).
MAC Address: C4:3D:C7:78:06:06 (Netgear)
Nmap scan report for 192.168.10.76
Host is up (0.040s latency).
MAC Address: C4:3D:C7:78:06:06 (Netgear)
```

or

```
Nmap scan report for 192.168.10.75
Host is up (0.0040s latency).
MAC Address: B8:27:EB:43:04:B5 (Raspberry Pi Foundation)
Nmap scan report for 192.168.10.76
Host is up (0.0030s latency).
MAC Address: B8:27:EB:43:04:B5 (Raspberry Pi Foundation)
```

This is seemingly dependent purely on what mood the Pi is in at the time.

When the Ethernet cable is unplugged from the Pi, it does not appear on the network at all. Through pure luck it remained on the network for a few minutes this morning, but then I had to leave for work and when I got back it was disconnected again.

Thanks in advance,

YM

Comment: You should probably ask this on the [Raspberry PI](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/) site.